# Poor performance of UNION query Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift UNION query that performs very poorly. Query goes like this:

```
WITH a1 AS (SELECT
            revenue_month,
            SUM(revenue) AS revenue,
            SUM(cost1) AS cost1,
            SUM(cost2) AS cost2,
            SUM(cost3) AS cost3
            FROM orders1
            GROUP BY revenue_month),

     a2 AS (SELECT
            revenue_month,
            SUM(revenue) AS revenue,
            SUM(cost1) AS cost1,
            SUM(cost2) AS cost2,
            SUM(cost3) AS cost3
            FROM orders2
            GROUP BY revenue_month),

     b1 AS (SELECT
            revenue_month,
            amount_type,
            SUM(amount) AS amount
            FROM monthly
            GROUP BY revenue_month,amount_type)
             
SELECT 'a1' AS data_set, 'revenue' AS amount_type, a1.revenue AS amount FROM a1 UNION
SELECT 'a1' AS data_set, 'cost1' AS amount_type, a1.cost1 AS amount FROM a1 UNION
SELECT 'a1' AS data_set, 'cost2' AS amount_type, a1.cost2 AS amount FROM a1 UNION
SELECT 'a1' AS data_set, 'cost3' AS amount_type, a1.cost3 AS amount FROM a1 UNION

SELECT 'a2' AS data_set, 'revenue' AS amount_type, a2.revenue AS amount FROM a2 UNION
SELECT 'a2' AS data_set, 'cost1' AS amount_type, a2.cost1 AS amount FROM a2 UNION
SELECT 'a2' AS data_set, 'cost2' AS amount_type, a2.cost2 AS amount FROM a2 UNION
SELECT 'a2' AS data_set, 'cost3' AS amount_type, a2.cost3 AS amount FROM a2 UNION

SELECT 'b1' AS data_set, b1.amount_type, b2.amount FROM b2
```

The goal of the UNION part is to transform a1 and a2 to have the same result set schema as b1 and eventually have one combined data set.

The a1 and a2 subqueries, when run on its own each takes around 60 secs to complete with 6000 rows, while b1 runs for 5 secs with 500 rows. These run-times are acceptable for me, however, the "combined" query above runs for a whopping 20 mins.

I think the fetching part is what takes too much time for this query. I have tried using UNION ALL but performance did not improve that much. If I can somehow transform a1 and a2 to b1 schema without having to use UNION would be great but I haven't been able to do so.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to unpivot the `a1` and `a2` tables.

I would do it like this:

```
WITH
     seq (idx) AS (
         select 'revenue' UNION ALL
         select 'cost1' UNION ALL
         select 'cost2' UNION ALL
         select 'cost3'
     ),
     a1 AS (SELECT
                revenue_month,
                SUM(revenue) AS revenue,
                SUM(cost1) AS cost1,
                SUM(cost2) AS cost2,
                SUM(cost3) AS cost3
            FROM orders1
            GROUP BY revenue_month),

     a2 AS (SELECT
                revenue_month,
                SUM(revenue) AS revenue,
                SUM(cost1) AS cost1,
                SUM(cost2) AS cost2,
                SUM(cost3) AS cost3
            FROM orders2
            GROUP BY revenue_month),

     b1 AS (SELECT
                revenue_month,
                amount_type,
                SUM(amount) AS amount
            FROM monthly
            GROUP BY revenue_month,amount_type)

SELECT
    'a1' AS data_set,
    seq.idx AS amount_type,
    CASE seq.idx
       WHEN 'revenue' THEN a1.revenue
       WHEN 'cost1' THEN a1.cost1
       WHEN 'cost2' THEN a1.cost2
       WHEN 'cost3' THEN a1.cost3
    END AS amount
FROM a1 CROSS JOIN seq

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'a2' AS data_set,
    seq.idx AS amount_type,
    CASE seq.idx
        WHEN 'revenue' THEN a1.revenue
        WHEN 'cost1' THEN a1.cost1
        WHEN 'cost2' THEN a1.cost2
        WHEN 'cost3' THEN a1.cost3
        END AS amount
FROM a2 CROSS JOIN seq

UNION ALL

SELECT 
       'b1' AS data_set, 
       b1.amount_type, 
       b1.amount 
FROM b1
```

Comment: Thanks man @botchniaque for the quick answer. I have tested that the CROSS JOIN approach transforms a1 and a2 correctly. However the final query when ran with the UNION ALL part of a1, a2 and b1 throws an error `XX000: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error`. I have checked this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html) but this query pattern is not included in that list. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: What is the exact query you're using? DId you use my example directly as is? Maybe moving unpivoting of `a1` and `a2` into their own cte's (`with a1_unpivot as (...), a2_unpivot as (...)`) would help?

Comment: I am confused by the error you're getting, as there's no subquery there.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your prompt replies! Really appreciate it. I also actually tried exactly what you have suggested - to move the "unpivoting" into their own ctes but oddly the same error was thrown. There's something with how redshift reads it when CROSS JOIN and UNION are both integrated in the query that it always fails with the same error but has no issues when individual ctes are run. However after playing around it all day, what worked for me is by transforming `b1` into the result schema of `a1` and `a2`, doing a `UNION` of the three ctes and then finally the `CROSS JOIN` to unpivot

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @botchniaque for all your help on this. Your `CROSS JOIN` suggestion solved this. There's something about that query pattern though that Redshift fails to read. The final query that worked for me is something like this:

```
WITH a1 AS (SELECT
            revenue_month,
            SUM(revenue) AS revenue,
            SUM(cost1) AS cost1,
            SUM(cost2) AS cost2,
            SUM(cost3) AS cost3
            FROM orders1
            GROUP BY revenue_month),

     a2 AS (SELECT
            revenue_month,
            SUM(revenue) AS revenue,
            SUM(cost1) AS cost1,
            SUM(cost2) AS cost2,
            SUM(cost3) AS cost3
            FROM orders2
            GROUP BY revenue_month),

     b1 AS (SELECT
            revenue_month,
            SUM(CASE WHEN amount_type = 'revenue' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS revenue,
            SUM(CASE WHEN amount_type = 'cost1' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS cost1,
            SUM(CASE WHEN amount_type = 'cost2' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS cost2,
            SUM(CASE WHEN amount_type = 'cost3' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS cost3

            FROM (SELECT
                  revenue_month,
                  amount_type,
                  SUM(amount) AS amount
                  FROM monthly
                  GROUP BY revenue_month,amount_type) AS b0
                  
            GROUP BY revenue_month)

SELECT
ab.data_set,
ab.revenue_month,
seq.amount_type,
CASE seq.amount_type
    WHEN 'revenue' THEN ab.revenue
    WHEN 'cost1' THEN ab.cost1
    WHEN 'cost2' THEN ab.cost2
    WHEN 'cost3' THEN ab.cost3
END AS amount

FROM            
            
(SELECT a1.revenue_month, a1.revenue, a1.cost1, a1.cost2, a1.cost3 FROM a1 UNION ALL
 SELECT a2.revenue_month, a2.revenue, a2.cost1, a2.cost2, a2.cost3 FROM a2 UNION ALL
 SELECT b1.revenue_month, b1.revenue, b1.cost1, b1.cost2, b1.cost3 FROM b1) AS ab
 
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'revenue' AS amount_type UNION ALL
             SELECT 'cost1' AS amount_type UNION ALL
             SELECT 'cost2' AS amount_type UNION ALL
             SELECT 'cost3' AS amount_type) AS seq
```

Basically it pivots `b1` first to have the same schema as `a1` and `a2`. And then combines all three datasets with `UNION` resulting to `ab`. And then finally unpivots the combined dataset with `CROSS JOIN`